# Search NSArray and add to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have an Xcode project with two NSArrays of objects, one named `completionArray` filled with `@"yes"` and `@"no"` and one named `allRequirements` with objects that represent college classes such as `@"ITCS 1215"`.  My goal is to search `completionArray` until I reach `@"no"`, then copy the object at that index from `allRequirements` in to `suggestionArray`, a NSMutableArray.

Here is my code so far, which does not work because it is throwing the error "Expected Identifier" after the last closing bracket.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.allRequirements count]; i++)
{
    if([self.completionArray[i] isEqual:@"no"])
        [self.suggestionArray addObject:[self.allRequirements[i]];
}
```

Thanks all.

Comment: Someone's gonna object that Xcode has nothing to do with it -- Xcode is just the IDE and you're programming in Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
[self.suggestionArray addObject:[self.allRequirements[i]];
```

to:

```
[self.suggestionArray addObject:self.allRequirements[i]];
```

Comment: That worked.  My coding partner and I tried a multitude of things and didn't see that.

Comment: If you really want to confuse yourself, change it to `[self.suggestionArray addObject:[self allRequirements][i]];`.  Or, better still, `[[self suggestionArray] addObject:[self allRequirements][i]];`

Comment: (Oh, and since allRequirements is apparently an NSArray, `[[self suggestionArray] addObject:[[self allRequirements] objectAtIndex:i]];`)